# Nuget Packager task - dependency is not added

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, azure-devops, nuget-package

I'm using Visual Studio Team Services to automate the creation of a nuget package. This package has a dependency on another nuget package (Newtonsoft.Json v8.0.3). I have configured a Nuget Packager task as part of the build:

[image: Nuget Packager task configuration]

But the generated package doesn't contain the reference to the nuget package:

[image: Generated nuget package without dependencies]

Running the following script on my local machine to generate the package:

```
nuget pack myproject.csproj -Symbols -IncludeReferencedProjects -Properties Configuration=Release -OutputDirectory bin/Release
```

I can see that the dependency is added to the generated package:

[image: Generated nuget package with dependencies]

What am I missing here? Why the dependencies are not being added to to package that is being generated on the build server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for my problem, even though I don't understand why the package was not being created properly.

So basically I have 2 builds:

- a "generic" build that will compile the entire solution and run unit tests, etc (automatic, triggered on commit)
- a build to generate the nuget package (manual)

This problem is on the 2nd build. I was trying to understand what were the differences between creating the package manually on my local machine and creating the package on the build server and I realized that on the build server I was not getting the source code for the solution, only for the project folder and the `.nuget` folder. Given that I have more than 40 projects in the solution it makes no sense to get the whole source code for the 2nd build, right? But for some reason this is not enough to generate the nuget package properly.

So, the solution to my problem was to get the source code for the following files/folders:

- Project folder
- `.nuget` folder (needed when restoring/installing the missing packages)
- Solution file (`mysolution.sln`)

Answer (score 0):

"IncludeReferencedProjects" is used to add the referenced project to the nuget package, not the referenced nuget packages.

> Include referenced projects either as dependencies or as part of the
>   package. If a referenced project has a corresponding nuspec file that
>   has the same name as the project, then that referenced project is
>   added as a dependency. Otherwise, the referenced project is added as
>   part of the package. Learn more at NuGet.org.

When you create the nuget package for the project which referenced to another nuget package. The nuget package dependency will be added automatically if the nupkg file exists in the packages folder. For your issue, you can add a "NuGet Installer" task in your build definition to restore the nuget package files for your solution. And then when you create the nuget package for your project, the referenced nuget package will be added as dependency.

Comment: Hi Eddie, yes I know the meaning of the flag, I've included it on my question just to show how I am creating the nuget package. The "Nuget Installer" task is already there but unfortunately it doesn't solve the problem, i.e. the Newtonsoft.Json dependency is not added.

Comment: @RuiJarimba I tried it at my side with Hosted Build Agent but didn't see any issue. By the way, which task are you using to create the nuget package? The UI in your question is different with mine.

Comment: @RuiJarimba And can you share the logs for "Nuget Installer" task and "Nuget Packager" task?

Comment: Hi Eddie, I have found a solution for my problem, I'll post it soon. I have a "NuGet Installer" task to install the missing packages for the project (Installation Type = Install) and a "NuGet Packager" task to create the package for the project.

Comment: Hi Eddie, check my answer. Any idea why the solution file is needed in order to generate the package with the right dependencies?

Comment: @RuiJarimba What's the setting of your "Nuget Installer" task?

Comment: `Path to solution or packages.config` is pointing to the `packages.config` file of the project; `Path to NuGet.config` is pointing to the `.nuget/NuGet.Config` file; `Installation type` is `Install`; `Disable local cache` is checked